# How to save an indexedrowmatrix to a local file orderly in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a blockmatrix and want to save it on my local disk in a single file.

```
val filepath = "hdfs://*********************"

object RowOrdering extends Ordering[IndexedRow] {
    def compare(a:IndexedRow, b:IndexedRow) = a.index compare b.index
}

blockmatrix.toIndexedRowMatrix.rows.map(x => x.vector.toDense).coalesce(1, true)(RowOrdering).saveAsTextFile(filepath)
```

But after I reloading the file

```
sc.textFile(path).take(1)(0)
```

It doesn't return the first line of the matrix. so, how can I save such a matrix while the order is still kept? thanks a lot!

Comment: What did you already try to attempt?

Comment: Try ‘repartition(1)’

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out. just use the command

```
blockmatrix.toIndexedRowMatrix.rows.sortBy(x => x.index).map(x => x.vector.toDense).saveAsTextFile(filepath)
```